# Is there an equivalent of iOS's Dynamic System Colors in Xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

When developing a Xamarin.iOS app, I have the ability to specify Dynamic system colors for backgroundColors to automatically adjust for light and dark mode.

For instance:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
{
    goalsCard.BackgroundColor = UIColor.SystemBackgroundColor;
}
else
{
    goalsCard.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
}
```

Now, when working with a .xaml file, and without using theming, I'd like to be able to do the same, for labels for example.

I have seen that I could say with an attribue:

> TextColor = {AppThemeBinding Dark=Black, Light=White}

But I want to let the target platform choose the appropriate colors for me, not to enforce them.

Actually, this simple Label (with no color explicitly specified) disappears in dark mode on iOS:

```
<Label Text="{this:Localize SavePassword}"
                 Font="Large"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Is that even possible with Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft docs has something here which looks similar to your need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes

```
<ContentPage ...>
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <Label Text="This text is green in light mode, and red in dark mode."
           TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Red}" />
    <Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=lightlogo.png, Dark=darklogo.png}" />
</StackLayout>
```

And then

```
<ContentPage ...>
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <!-- Light colors -->
    <Color x:Key="LightPrimaryColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LightSecondaryColor">Black</Color>

    <!-- Dark colors -->
    <Color x:Key="DarkPrimaryColor">Teal</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkSecondaryColor">White</Color>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightSecondaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkSecondaryColor}}" />
    </Style>

</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}">
  <Button Text="MORE INFO"
          Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This won't use the platform dynamic colors I'm afraid

Comment: So you want to let the platform decide what colour something should be of?

Comment: For [iOS basic colors](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/), yes.
Don't try to replicate dynamic system colors. Dynamic system colors may fluctuate from release to release, based on a variety of environmental variables. Instead of trying to create custom colors that match the system colors, use the dynamic system colors.